# C# OpenGL Проблема при перетаскивании объектов

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, drag-n-drop, opentk

Почему при перетаскивании объекта, он перетаскивается не конкретно с курсором, а слегка обтекая его (попытался отобразить на скриншотах ниже)?

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3]

На скриншотах, по порядку:
1. Начинаю тянуть за центр объекта
2. Если оттягиваю мышь влево
3. Если оттягиваю мышь вверх

Вправо и вниз, соответственно, ситуация та же.
Ниже приведу фрагменты своего кода.

Объект будто опаздывает за курсором.

Метод при перемещении мыши:

```
    private void MainWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseMoveEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            if (CardManager.SelectedCard != null)
            {
                Ray.Create(e.X, e.Y, camera);
                Vector3 prePos = CardManager.SelectedCard.IntersectionPoint;
                float planeDist = camera.Position.Z - prePos.Z;
                Vector3 curPos = -Ray.Direction * (planeDist / Ray.Direction.Z) + camera.Position;
                CardManager.SelectedCard.IntersectionPoint = curPos;

                curPos = curPos - prePos;

                CardManager.SelectedCard.object3d.translationMatrix *= Matrix4.CreateTranslation(curPos);
            }
        }
    }
```

Как я получаю **IntersectionPoint** из этой строки:

```
Vector3 prePos = CardManager.SelectedCard.IntersectionPoint;
```

В этом методе:

```
    public bool RayIntersect(Vector3 rayStart, Vector3 rayDir, Camera camera)
    {
        Vector3 cmin = Vector3.TransformPosition(object3d.objectMin, object3d.Object3DMatrix);
        Vector3 cmax = Vector3.TransformPosition(object3d.objectMax, object3d.Object3DMatrix);
        Vector3 rs = rayStart;
        Vector3 rd = rayDir;
        Vector3 diff0 = cmin - rs;
        Vector3 diff1 = cmax - rs;
        Vector3 t0 = new Vector3(diff0.X / rd.X, diff0.Y / rd.Y, diff0.Z / rd.Z);
        Vector3 t1 = new Vector3(diff1.X / rd.X, diff1.Y / rd.Y, diff1.Z / rd.Z);
        Vector3 tMin = new Vector3(Math.Min(t0.X, t1.X), Math.Min(t0.Y, t1.Y), Math.Min(t0.Z, t1.Z));
        Vector3 tMax = new Vector3(Math.Max(t0.X, t1.X), Math.Max(t0.Y, t1.Y), Math.Max(t0.Z, t1.Z));
        float tnear = Math.Max(Math.Max(tMin.X, tMin.Y), tMin.Z);
        float tfar = Math.Min(Math.Min(tMax.X, tMax.Y), tMax.Z);
        if (tnear <= tfar)
        {
            IntersectionPoint = rd * tnear + camera.Position;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Класс **Ray**:

```
public static class Ray
{
    public static Vector3 Start = Vector3.Zero;
    public static Vector3 End = Vector3.Zero;
    public static Vector3 Direction = Vector3.Zero;

    public static void Create(int mouse_x, int mouse_y, Camera camera)
    {
        int[] viewport = new int[4];
        GL.GetInteger(GetPName.Viewport, viewport);
        Start = new Vector3(mouse_x, mouse_y, 0.0f).UnProject(camera, new Size(viewport[2], viewport[3]));
        End = new Vector3(mouse_x, mouse_y, 1.0f).UnProject(camera, new Size(viewport[2], viewport[3]));
        Direction = End - Start;
        Direction.Normalize();
    }
}
```

И метод **UnProject**:

```
    public static Vector3 UnProject(this Vector3 mouse, Camera camera, Size viewport)
    {
        Vector4 vec;
        vec.X = 2.0f * mouse.X / viewport.Width - 1;
        vec.Y = -(2.0f * mouse.Y / viewport.Height - 1);
        vec.Z = mouse.Z;
        vec.W = 1.0f;
        Matrix4 projInv = Matrix4.Invert(camera.ProjectionPerspectiveMatrix);
        Matrix4 viewInv = Matrix4.Invert(camera.ViewMatrix);
        Vector4.Transform(ref vec, ref projInv, out vec);
        Vector4.Transform(ref vec, ref viewInv, out vec);
        if (vec.W > 0.000001f || vec.W < -0.000001f)
        {
            vec.X /= vec.W;
            vec.Y /= vec.W;
            vec.Z /= vec.W;
        }

        return vec.Xyz;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в неверном способе нахождения точки пересечения луча и объекта (**IntersectionPoint**) в методе **RayIntersect**.

Нужно заменить

```
IntersectionPoint = rd * tnear + camera.Position;
```

на

```
IntersectionPoint = rd * tnear + rs;
```